# I need a list of geographical places where the article "THE" is used

Tags: articles

I need a list of places where the article "THE" is used

For example:

The USA but not "the" India"

Why does one country have the article *the* and the other not?

Comment: related: [Using the definite article before a country/state name](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name); [Need for using the article “the” before “United States of America”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127137/need-for-using-the-article-the-before-united-states-of-america)

Comment: [Why is Ukraine often called “the Ukraine”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58735/why-is-ukraine-often-called-the-ukraine/58744#58744), [Why 'The' is used?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85601/why-the-is-used)

Comment: Here is a list of geographical places that use the article "the" in front: [a list of countries which use the definite article "the".](http://www.engvid.com/english-resource/the-with-country-names-lakes-rivers/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA it may be related. Soviet Union and now Russia insists on saying "na Ukraine" instead of "v Ukraine" (на Украине - В Украине) - It irritates the Ukrainians no end lately for obvious reasons. It may be that the name is derived from "Oкраина" which means something like suburb. Hence when using _na_ one does not recognise Ukraine as a proper country.

Answer (score 0):

India is a name, so you cannot put 'the' before it, like you could not say 'the Steve' in most cases. The USA refers to all the states, 'The United States', whereas if you would refer to the USA as America, you could not say 'The America'. Long story short, in most cases you cannot put 'the' before names, but there are exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Man... Could u please tell me.. what are the other places that begins with definite article "THE"

Comment: This is a good description/definition: A definite article indicates that its noun is a particular one (or ones) identifiable to the listener. It may be something that the speaker has already mentioned, or it may be something uniquely specified. The definite article in English, for both singular and plural nouns, is the. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29#Definite_article . For the list of countries, see Mari-LouA's comment.