# Why is there an indefinite article before "London"?

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns, indefinite-articles

> Two years after his reported Reichenbach Fall demise, Sherlock, who has been cleared of all fraud charges against him, returns with Mycroft's help to **a London** under threat of terrorist attack.

I know, there are [city names with articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28177/68719) (like "The Hague"), but I've never heard someone say "a London" till now.

Is "a London under threat of terrorist attack" used here as a description of some indefinite place in London?

Comment: *London* stands for "city", which is a countable noun. "...  a city (London) under threat of terrorist attack."

Comment: In addition to the other answers, if you remove the "a", then it becomes ambiguous as to whether it is London or Sherlock who is under threat.

Comment: Consider that there are multiple Londons, if you consider each point in time to be a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This construction gives a sense of renewal of acquaintance or a rediscovery. Note that you can also employ the definite article.

Example:

> I returned to Anthea's house after many years to find *an Anthea* who no longer laughed and sang. She was now a sad reflection of *the Anthea* I used to know.

You can think of it as meaning "a version of".

> I returned to Anthea's house after many years to find *a version of Anthea* who no longer laughed and sang. She was now a sad reflection of *the version of Anthea* I used to know.

There is a sense that Anthea, or London, could be in many different states. You have returned to discover which state exists in real life.

I hope that helps.