# Argentine or Argentinian?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms, proper-nouns, variants

I was taught in my school days that *Argentine* was the correct adjective for something relating to the country Argentina. However, these days, even in common speech (but moreover in formal English on new channels even), the form *Argentinian* used.

My question is, is *Argentine* in fact the correct form and *Argentinian* a misconstruction of the adjective done out of ignorance, is conversely the latter correct, or are both correct in fact? In the final case, I would be curious which came first and was traditionally more common in usage in the English language.

Comment: related: [Using the definite article before a country/state name](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)

Comment: Since both of these words are also used as nouns ("Argentinians live in Argentina.") I'm adding noun tags too.

Comment: I should also add that a third variant has been on the rise since the late 1980s, *Argentinean*, in both American and British English.

Comment: @hippietrail: May be on the rise, but it's still very rarely used, at least in the UK. I've never seen it written.

Comment: @Noldorin: I tried to find some UK and Ireland online news using *Argentinean*, football contexts seem more common: [Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/competitions/premier-league/10298730/Southampton-v-West-Ham-United-live.html), [Indepenent Woman](http://www.independent.ie/woman/celeb-news/is-that-you-joe-its-the-holy-father-29580423.html), [Worcester News](http://www.worcesternews.co.uk/sport/10672744.Senatore_links_up_with_Warriors_on_Monday/).

Comment: @Noldorin: [Tottenham & Wood Green Journal](http://www.tottenhamjournal.co.uk/tottenham-hotspur/tottenham-hotspur/spurs_boss_eriksen_can_emulate_sneijder_and_van_der_vaart_1_2417659), [Sun](http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/news/5128306/fifa-14s-star-studded-tv-ad-with-gareth-bale.html), [Mancunian Matters](http://mancunianmatters.co.uk/content/100912426-were-best-team-town-super-striker-sergio-aguero-believes-manchester-city-have-squa), [The News](http://www.portsmouth.co.uk/news/business/local-business/segensworth-firm-gains-a-chile-order-1-5472002).

Comment: @hippietrail: Don't read any of those publications. I still think it's fair to say it's a relatively very rare (and in my quite odd) usage.

Comment: Depends what you compare it too I suppose. It might be relatively rare compared to the most popular variant but it's very common compared to how rare it was in say 1985. Its rise was [quite sharp](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Argentinean&year_start=1982&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=), and it's edging [closer to *Argentinian*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Argentinean%2CArgentinian&year_start=1982&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=), which has been in an even sharper decline. All seem like noteworthy trends so I'm just noting them (-:

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. The funny thing is, I notice people using "Argentinian" everywhere, from everyday conversations, to the media, even to newspapers... which I still consider incorrect and born out of ignorance.

Comment: @hippietrail: For adding the noun tag, the answer to the question of which word to use for the noun may differ than the answer to the question about which word to use as the adjective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't really an answer. It's just to back up @GEdgar's chart showing that *Argentine* is overwhelmingly the standard form, but that *Argentinian* does occur.
[image]

I'm not going to look for "authoritative" sources. There's been debate about these two words for years, so obviously it's not clear-cut. Without checking, I expect there will be pedants who want *Argentine* restricted to the *silver-like* meaning, and historians who point out that we used to call the country itself *The Argentine*, so the inhabitants must be called something else.

I think what happens is most of us rarely need either word, so we don't really know or care which is "correct". As shown by [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Argentine,Argentinian&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3), Brits (but not Americans) started using *Argentinian* more after WW2 ended (we imported lots of beef), and after the Falklands war (which we all talked about).

After each of those "peaks", the alternative non-standard form gradually faded as the people using it realised they were in a minority. But because educated people never use *Argentinian* for the *silvery* meaning, there are always some people who want to keep that for the nationality. But there are never enough people thinking like that, so it fades away again.

Comment: I think it *is* an answer. +1

Comment: There is an issue with the nGram chart, that you cannot tell when the usage is as an adjective or noun, and if a noun whether it is being used for the country's name or one of its citizens.

Comment: @Henry: As I said, my answer is an adjunct to GEdgar's, where we *know* it's an adjective because it's being applied to *woman*. *The Argentine* was pre-WW2 British for the country, but you can factor that in when you look at my chart. I know some people would like the [demonym](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/demonymterm.htm) (for the citizens) to be different to the adjectival form, but I am not one of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you for this answer. It does indeed fill in the missing bits of information I was hoping for. I suppose I wasn't too clear in my question, but I'm glad you "interpolated" in this case. I think my experience agrees with your assertions in any case, except perhaps that I hear Argentinian commonly used in spoken English (in particular by less well-educated folk but also by well-educated folk.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the 1950s we called the country *The Argentine*. Indeed my father, who had been in the meat trade never ceased calling it that. I am unsure of the history to this. Was it anything like that of *The Ukraine* ? That was a designation long encouraged by Russians but which Ukrainian nationalists rejected.

Answer (score 9):

In British usage, Argentina is the country, Argentines are its citizens and Argentinian is its derived adjective.

Comment: I can't agree that *Argentinian is its derived adjective*. It's an available alternative, but *Argentine* is the primary adjective. Meat is definitely not a form of "citizenry", but *Argentine beef* is [much more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Argentine+beef%2CArgentinian+beef&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *Argentinian beef*.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm with @fumbleFingers here. Argentine was the original form of the adjective; closer to Spanish, and I am happy to say more common in writing thanks to the NGram chart below.

Comment: Though I do agree *Argentinian* is more commonly used in spoken word (however much it annoys me). Personally, I'd rather just cut off the extra syllable at the end!

Answer (score 5):

I think Argentinian is probably more common in English.

Although the official name of the country is "Argentine Republic" which is "Argentina" in spanish. Just to confuse things "The Argentine" was used in English as the name of the country at least until the middle of the 20C

Comment: Interesting. The official name of the country suggests *Argentine* was the traditional/original correct adjective. Argentinian is more common in *spoken* English quite possibly (not in written, as shown by the NGram), though I still want to believe this stems from ignorance.

Comment: The "official" name is *República Argentina*. There isn't some special international authority defining the official translation into English for all countries using that language. Brits sometimes use the conventional long form *Argentine Republic*, but both we and the Argentine people use the same conventional short form *Argentina*.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Argentine%20woman,Argentinian%20woman&year_start=1880&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

[image]

Comment: -1 for linking to external resources without providing any real answer. The link becoming dead renders your answer completely useless.

Comment: Uploaded.  Better?

Comment: @RiMMERΨ Seems a bit overly hostile..

Comment: @GEdgar: great to see the NGram, but it really needs some more commentary + context to make an answer to the question.

Comment: I think the NGram makes the point clearly enough without any further commentary. But if you want the longer version, check with *women* rather than *woman*, and compare US/UK usage. Because of the Falklands, we Brits are more conscious of the issue anyway, and we almost *always* say **Argentine women**.

Comment: Thanks for this chart. It definitely tells a good deal. For example, *Argentine* is clearly the original form, and unsurprisingly given its greater similarity to the Spanish adjective *Argentino*. *Argentinian* seems to have enjoyed steady but still lesser version since 1960; obviously the peak is around the time of the Falklands war...

Comment: Anyway, if you care to add a bit of history/quote official sources, I would definitely be tempted to accept this as the answer. :-)

Comment: @Noldorin: What more do you want? You say yourself *Argentine* is clearly the original form. [Here's](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=447220) one of many discussions on it, which mostly end by saying "it's a matter of taste". It's no good asking the [Argentine government](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Argentine+government%2CArgentinian+government&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) because they speak Spanish, so their word is **Argentino**, as you know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yeah, I suppose. I sorted of wanted an OED-style assertion stating "First recorded in 1650, in xyz" or such, but maybe I'm too picky! Or a cited confirmation by a lexicographer/linguist that the *Argentinian* form stemmed from misusage/ignorance - that would be nice.

Comment: @Noldorin: So you don't really want to know the "standard" word (i.e. - the one that most people use), and it doesn't matter that the alternative is used and understood? Perhaps I can post you a more convincing picture...

Answer (score -1):

I would say:
**Argentina**: the country.
 **Argentine**: Adjetive for things like argentine music, argentine wine,argentine food, etc.
 **Argentinean** or **Argentinian**: Demonym for people, i.e. I am argentinean, argentinean are friendly people, Nationality: Argentinean. This means people "from" the country Argentina are argentinean.

Comment: Whichever words you use, they should all begin with a capital **A** in written English.