# Is it "the Yemen" or "Yemen"?

Tags: etymology

There's a film just out called *Salmon fishing in the Yemen*.

I've also heard people talk about the country Yemen as "the Yemen".

Is it wrong to call Yemen "The Yemen" - or does it date back to some colonial era, where that was what people said?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the definite article before a country/state name](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See also [Using the definite article before a country/state name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name) .

The names of regions often take the definite article, especially if they are named after a natural feature such as a river or mountain, as in "the Congo" or "the Lebanon." Before Yemen was the name of a country, it was a historical region, and called "the Yemen" much like "the Argentine" or "the Gold Coast."

The article has fallen out of use in some cases (e.g. Sudan for the Republic of the Sudan), in other cases it is officially discouraged (e.g. Ukraine, not the Ukraine), in others it is part of the name and always included (e.g. The Gambia), and in still others it is not considered part of the name but is nevertheless always included (e.g. the United Kingdom).

I am not sure of the era when the film is set. It is possible that "the Yemen" is what the main character, an Brit, would have called that region in that time, or that the old name is used deliberately to highlight a prejudice or neo-colonial attitude toward Yemen on his part.

Answer (score 5):

It may be [something else entirely](http://www.boxofficeprophets.com/column/index.cfm?columnID=14777), like salmon fishing in the Columbia, or the Amazon, or the Nile.

It’s not like people call British Columbia ***“the*** Columbia”.  It’s a river.

Answer (score 5):

tchrist is right.  From the description of a movie:

> A British fisheries expert is cast to bring to life a sheik’s vision of spawning hope and peace for his people through the introduction of salmon into the Yemen River.

Comment: *Salmon Fishing in the Yemen* was previously a book, with that same plot.

Answer (score 3):

*The Yemen* is technically correct, as *yemen* means *south*. (Or, to be
really precise, *on the right-hand side*, the assumption in Arabic being
that you describe directions as if you were facing the sunrise.) But only
an extraordinarily pedantic person would object to *Yemen*.

This etymology implies using *the* because in English, when you make a
proper noun (i.e. a name) out of a description or a common noun, you insert
the definite article, *the*. This is just an example of the standard use of
*the*, which is to indicate that a phrase which could apply to many
different things is actually being used to refer to one particular
pre-selected thing. The rule is compulsory if the description or common
noun is in English (*the Gulf*, not **Gulf*; *the Cape*, not **Cape*),
but if it’s in a foreign language it may be optional, this being largely
determined by common usage.  So definitely *the Netherlands*, (*the
Lowlands*), not **Netherlands* (*Lowlands*), but on the other hand,
definitely *Detroit*, (*Strait*) not **the Detroit* (*the Strait*), while
you get the choice in *(the) Yemen* and *(the) Ukraine*.

The names of rivers almost always get a *the*, but this is a quite separate
and less logical convention, as it applies whatever the derivation of the
river’s name. While it seems that the countries the Congo and the Gambia
inherit their *the*’s from the corresponding rivers, that explanation can’t
apply to the Yemen, as there is no river there with that name. In fact
there are no rivers there at all, only seasonal wadis.

Of course, the *the* is there in the country’s Arabic name *al-Jumhūrīyah
al-Yamanīyah*, literally *the Republic of the South*.  This adds force to
the argument, but it is not necessary. For instance, the Russian name for
the Crimea is *Krim*, with no definite article, since Russian doesn’t have
any articles at all. But educated Russians are taught that the word means
*fortress* in Tartar, so if they are also fluent in English, they will tend
to call it *the Crimea* rather than just *Crimea*, and this has carried
over into educated English.

The choice of *the Ukraine* or *Ukraine* has become politicized.  Until the
breakup of the Soviet Union in the early 1990’s almost everyone used the
*the*, and omitting it was widely considered an error. This is because, as
described on the Wikipedia page *Name_of_Ukraine*, the name is standardly
derived from the word for *borderland* in Slavic languages. (Hence also
*the Krajina*, the borderland between Serbia and Croatia — the
pronunciations are very similar in the original languages.) The Ukraine was
the borderland between Russia on the one side and the Polish-Lithuanian
Commonwealth and the Ottoman Empire on the other. But as the Wikipedia
article notes, *during the period of Romantic nationalism it was popular to
trace the origin of the country name to an ancient ethnonym,* which is
sometimes given as *the Ukrs*. That would imply no article — the land of
the Angles is *England*, not **the England*, and the land of the Franks is
*France*, not **the France*, so the land of the Ukrs should be *Ukraine*, not
**the Ukraine*.

A couple of years after independence, the new Ukrainian state changed the
approved English form from *the Ukraine* to *Ukraine*, presumably under the
influence of *Romantic Nationalists* who wanted to suppress any reminders
that Ukrainian identity was actually just a renaming of Malorossian, i.e.
Little Russian, identity, and instead wanted to see it as derived from the
mythical Ukrs, who supposedly predated Russia by thousands of years.
(*Little Russia* means the original heartland of Russia, as opposed to
*Great(er) Russia*, the areas expanded into later. See the paragraph
starting *[Just to clarify](http://thesaker.is/city-of-sevastopol-officials-are-threatening-to-create-their-own-sovereign-state/)* from the blogger known as The
Saker, who incidentally gets his *the* by exactly the mechanism being
discussed here.) Though The Saker doesn’t mind if other people leave out
the *the* from *the Ukraine*, he gets [very irritated](http://thesaker.is/moderation-policy/) with people who
impudently tell him that he must do the same, as he sees that as a demand
that he should suppress the truth for the sake of a divisive and false
politically-inspired mythology.

Comment: Please stop putting capitalized articles on proper nouns. That is incorrect English.

Comment: @tchrist It's [**not** incorrect](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/gambia) for The Gambia. (Also in [The Gambia government site](http://moici.gov.gm/), although that seems a bit slower)

Comment: Is this a British English vs. American English thing? As a Brit, I'd feel it very disrespectful to deprive The Saker of his capital-T.

Comment: ELU revolves around English, but I for one am willing to call people pretty much whatever they want to be called. At minimum, the Yemeni government should confirm the real name with [en.wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yemen). In some way, it helps to know the people of (The?) Ukraine are still arguing about their name. Just wondering: does anyone in [Yemen](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/yemen.htm) prefer *The Yemen*, or is this just a pedantic argument of translation of an ancient moniker? We need the people of (The?) Yemen to come out of the closet about their real name!

Comment: I would prefer to stand on the friendly side of The Saker. All the military analysts I know are friends, and it seems wise to keep it that way :-)

Comment: Thanks to @ScottM for editing my post to show object language in italics rather than quotation marks, and for the asterisks for non-approved forms. (However, "during the period of Romantic nationalism..." and "Romantic Nationalists" are genuine quotes, and would be better with quotation marks.) I should have taken the time to establish the local conventions in force before posting. I'd found this site via Google, and didn't realise it was for serious linguists!

Comment: On _the_ vs _The_ , I'd tend to tolerate anything but intolerance. My own productive idiolect would certainly give _The Saker_ the capital-_T_, but on reflection I suspect that that is not so much because he _is_ a person than because he is _not_ actually a falcon. Because he isn't really a saker, the whole phrase _The Saker_ can only be interpreted as  a genuine personal name, and is therefore capitalised throughout. The character in the Batman magazines, on the other hand, actually _is_ a joker, so _the Joker_ is fine.

Comment: Personally, I'd also distinguish when writing between the rivers _the Congo_ and _the Gambia_ and the countries _The Congo_ and _The Gambia_. But I have no logical argument or empirical evidence that my habits are more correct then anyone else's.

Looking at my original posting, it seems that outside those two areas, my usage is fairly random, possibly just following what I have been most frequently exposed to. While I don't think that there is anything wrong with that practice, for the sake of tidiness and consistency, I will try in future to conform to @tchrist's preference for a small _t_.