# significance of "The" before country name

Tags: definite-articles, proper-nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the definite article before a country/state name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)

I am from India, and I do not say that I am from “the India”. But someone from USA  would say “I am from **the** United States of America.” Why do you need to use the extra  “the” in the second case?

Comment: India is a proper noun. Though name of country is the Republic of India.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very simply:

If the country name is common nouns, use *the* - the Czech Republic, the United Kingdom.

If it is a group of islands, use *the* - the Bahamas, the Maldives.

If it the name is common nouns followed by 'of', use *the* - the United States of America, the Peoples Republic of China.

If the name is taken from a geographical feature, you should use *the* - the Yemen, the Lebanon. This last one is declining though.

*India* is just a plain old proper noun, like a persons name, and hence takes no article.

Comment: Apart from http://fishingintheyemen.com/? There's a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68901/is-it-the-yemen-or-yemen) too.

Comment: "Often heard with 'the': Argentine, Congo, Gambia, Yemen, Lebanon, Sudan, Netherlands, Philippines, Bahamas, Ukraine"  -> http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-18233844  I agree that I haven't often heard 'The Yemen' outside that excellent film, but I have rarely heard 'the Sudan' or the 'the Lebanon' either.

Comment: I always use *The* with all those names, but then I'm reactionary.

Comment: @Andrew: Do you mean "retrograde" or "retrogressive" (tending towards or resulting in a worse state {retrograde ideas})  rather than "reactionary" (wanting to preserve outmoded traditions).

Comment: No, I meant reactionary.

Comment: Just checking. Interesting.

Comment: "the Russian Federation" or "Russian Federation"?