# Why do we use "the" in "the British" but not before "Canadians"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, demonyms

Why do we use the definite article before most nationalities such as "the British" but we say "Canadians" without *the*?

Specifically, why is it that, for example,...

> *Canadians like maple syrup.*

...is a normal/unremarkable statement/sentence, but...

> **British think they put on a "jolly good show" for the 2012 Olympics.*

...is "incorrect" without a leading definite article?

Comment: I use "the" before both. "The British speak the same language as the Canadians."

Comment: @Luke How about the other way around?

Comment: The Canadians speak the same language as the British?

Comment: You're mixing two kinds of names. "Canadians" is analogous to "Britons", not to "the British". "Britons" refers to *some* people; "the British" refers to *a* people.

Comment: Related: [“Using the definite article before a country/state name”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name).

Comment: @Alisa: I don't understand the closevotes - as I write, **three** people are saying it's "Not a Real Question". I'll edit your text, but if you don't like the changes, please feel free to edit it again yourself.

Comment: I have no idea how this is _not a real question_ either.

Comment: FWIW I think it's a great question.

Comment: @MετάEd, I'd be more inclined to believe that argument if you could come up with a version of "Canadian" that *does* take an article. In other words, Briton:Canadian::British:??? (Note that to me, "the Canadians" sounds totally wrong unless we're talking about a particular group of tourists or something. Ditto for "the Americans".)

Comment: @Marthaª The point is that there are two terms for British people, and that the question is comparing "Canadians" with the wrong one. If there are two terms for Canadians I am not aware of it, and I am surely not inclined to try to invent another one.

Comment: Distantly related: [Why is “I like to study the English” wrong?](//english.stackexchange.com/q/328162/26083)

Comment: The reason we need to use "the" with "British" is because "British" is not a noun. Demonyms with -an, like "Canadian", can be nouns or adjectives, but are used exclusively as plural nouns without article when speaking abstractly about the demographic as a whole. Demonyms with -ish, like "British", are exclusively adjectives, and so use a different construction. Two in fact: With the noun "people" and no article, or with no noun and the article "the".

Answer (score 9):

["While the Canadians"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22while%20the%20canadians%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) may not always *require* the definite article, there are over 10,000 written instances showing they're quite capable of taking it on board.

[We British, on the other hand](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22while%20the%20canadians%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22We%20British%20on%20the%20other%20hand%22&oq=%22We%20British%20on%20the%20other%20hand%22&gs_l=serp.3...5770.8922.2.9280.15.15.0.0.0.1.311.1090.13j1j0j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.HvtrKus6MAg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886), can only do without it in constructions like that (where *"We..."* effectively stands in for *"We, **the**..."*).

It's probably connected to the fact that we have an alternative [demonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) that *doesn't* normally take a definite article...

> ["Americans, Canadians, and **Britons**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22while%20the%20canadians%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Americans%20Canadians%20and%20Britons%22&oq=%22Americans%20Canadians%20and%20Britons%22&gs_l=serp.3...5702.8405.3.9843.4.4.0.0.0.0.62.219.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.0AiSH5hD-q4&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886) are all anglophones.
>
> (as are ["The Americans, the Canadians, and the British"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20Americans%20the%20Canadians%20and%20the%20British%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1))

Per MετάEd's comment to the question itself, *the British* normally refers collectively to *a people*, so you'll see things like [The British are an industrious race](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the+british+are+an+industrious%22&oq=%22the+british+are+an+industrious%22&gs_l=serp.3...145748.155770.6.156187.61.43.0.0.0.13.174.3500.37j6.43.0...0.0...1c.1.L-20xFjp9oc&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886). But in contexts where *multiple individuals* are being referenced, we'd normally say something like [Four Britons were among the dead.](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22four+britons+were+among+the+dead%22&oq=%22four+britons+were+among+the+dead%22&gs_l=serp.3...5571.7522.5.7803.9.9.0.0.0.0.82.607.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.X_AtiHYyoyc&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886)

---

It's interesting to consider the position of the French here. [Several **French** were among them](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=P6MhAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Several%20French%20were%20among%22&dq=%22Several%20French%20were%20among%22&source=bl&ots=bfaKtO39Tw&sig=ENKwiXcqDtrZocQ6vZwr-tw9kOc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2PVsUIbZBueh0QWkz4GgAg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA) is *really* unusual (that was the only clear-cut example I could easily find in Google Books), whereas [two **Frenchmen** were among [them]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Several%20French%20were%20among%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22two%20Frenchmen%20were%20among%22&oq=%22two%20Frenchmen%20were%20among%22&gs_l=serp.3...4351.6032.4.6422.6.6.0.0.0.0.105.389.5j1.6.0...0.0...1c.1.UP4STnXXGKs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886) is unexceptional. I don't know what the disaster reporters would write if the French casualties were a man and a woman, but not actually [a French couple](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Several%20French%20were%20among%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22were%20a%20French%20couple%22&oq=%22were%20a%20French%20couple%22&gs_l=serp.3...5088.8636.8.9009.10.10.0.0.0.0.57.478.10.10.0...0.0...1c.1.mEErM7OQL6Q&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886).

Comment: +1 Is _Brit_ considered an abbreviation of _British_ or _Briton_ or both? I ask because it doesn't seem to require said article.

Comment: @coleopterist: I don't think I can answer that one, even speaking just for myself! If I'm forced to, I'd say I see *Brit* as about equally split between being an abbreviation *(of **British, Briton, Britisher**, again, all about equal)*, and a "standalone" word that doesn't *have* to be seen as an abbreviation of any one of them in particular.