# How to use the article "the" properly

Tags: british-english

I've heard people saying "I am going to town", why can't it be "I am going to *the* town"?

And why is it "I go to *the* city" and not "I go to city"?

Comment: Because English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't there a "the" in "I left work", but there is in "I left the office"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/401207/why-isnt-there-a-the-in-i-left-work-but-there-is-in-i-left-the-office) (with 'I left New York'
 ... 

'I left [the] school'
'I left [the] church').

Comment: ...Also see [I saw Sue in town yesterday – why is there no article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274220/i-saw-sue-in-town-yesterday-but-she-didnt-see-me-why-is-there-no-article-be/274230#274230) with anarthrous usages of 'town':  '... 'Cam left town about an hour ago, so he should be out at the farm by now' 
'I'll be out of town for about a week' 'Guess who's in town? Jodie's sister!' 
'Do you know of a good place to eat?'  'I'm from out of town (=from a different town)' 
'We're moving to another part of town' ...

Comment: See also [Which nouns should include an article after "go to {noun}" in AmE and BE?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172745/which-nouns-should-include-an-article-after-go-to-noun-in-ame-and-be) and [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they "go to hospital"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital).

Comment: See also [Which nouns should include an article after "go to {noun}" in AmE and BE?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172745/which-nouns-should-include-an-article-after-go-to-noun-in-ame-and-be) and [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they "go to hospital"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital). *Barrie England suggests a rationale for the 'to town' usage at ['to school' versus 'to garage'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58103/to-school-versus-to-garage).

Answer (score 0):

*In town* and *to town* are stock phrases meaning *in/to our nearby town/city.* It used also to be used of London, as in the former BBC radio programme [In town tonight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Town_Tonight). As @HotLicks implies, there is no logical reason for this (except that, in London, *the City* refers to the business district).