# Before the abbreviation of country name is definite article required?

Tags: grammar

Before the abbreviation of country name is definite article required?
for example USA .
He arrived in USA. 
Is the sentence correct?
Should we use 'the USA'?

Comment: It depends entirely on the place—and the word. You would not say *in the America* or *in the England*, but you would say *in the USA* and *in the UK*. However, just because it's an abbreviation that doesn't mean the article is prescribed. You would not say *in the NZ (New Zealand)*, nor would you say *in the LA (Los Angeles)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the definite article before a country/state name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)