# Do we use "the" when referring to United Kingdom?

Tags: grammar

Do we always have to use "the" before "United Kingdom" (or "UK")?

Comment: Usually we capitalize the first letters of "United Kingdom".

Comment: There is only one.

Comment: This is common for countries with descriptive nouns in their names such as the United States, the Russian Federation, the People's Republic of China etc. in contrast to America, Russia, China etc.  You do not need it when used adjectivally as in "she is a UK politician".

Comment: Yes, John, we use "the" in almost all circumstances.

When we don't, you will surely get more help somewhere like English Language Learners.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the definite article before a country/state name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)