# Is this correct? Canada, Spain, and USA

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Substitute USA with UK, UAE, and the equivalent, is it correct?

Or do I have to add the definite article prior to USA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the definite article before a country/state name](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/using-the-definite-article-before-a-country-state-name)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to be absolutely correct, use the definite article before some country names, even when abbreviated: The Netherlands, the United Kingdom, the United States, The People's Republic of China (and others).

In the current *Chicago Manual of Style*, the definite article is used in some cases and not others. It gives these examples for abbreviating "United States" but doesn't discuss the definite article:

US dollars
US involvement in China
China’s involvement in the US

I would say using the definite article is definitely not needed when listing countries, such as in a table or other non-sentence format:

**Countries:**
France
Germany
USA
Netherlands